# Why they are much younger?

Tags: plot-explanation, american-horror-story

In American Horror story, Season 6, in the first episode, It’s weird to me that both actors for main characters in the past are much older than the actors for the main characters who are telling the story.

Why is that? Particular reason regarding the show or just a bad actors chose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not found an Out-of-Universe reason for this but In-Universe, this might make some sense.

We know the producer is fairly successful so he wants to get the best actors for the reenactment that he can afford, not necessarily the ones that match the original people's ages or looks.

When it comes to watching reenactments on television (especially for "supernatural" types of shows), the actors rarely resemble the people they are portraying too closely.

Comment: I think this is pretty accurate, but I also might speculate that it in terms of how AHS writers went about it, also provided an unique aesthetic contrast (juxtaposition) from "real life" to "fictionalized documentary" to play on something sensationable or perhaps an irony. I haven't seen the series so, I don't know if what happened to the real couple is real, or if they lied a great deal about the circumstance of their misfortune to make the documentary to make money, but then supernatural things ensued upon the move to NC? If so, it would suggest some kind of karma, payback, dark irony too.

Comment: I *highly* recommend that season, more than the Cult season that followed but not as much as the Hotel one that preceded it